# Empty Mobile Number is Callable in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

When implementing call feature. Noticed that empty strings are returning true in call checking using canOpenURL

```
   let mobile = ""

    if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(mobile)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
```

Above code works perfectly and instead of asking user confirmation for making call, **an alert being displayed without any title or message from OS**. Is it bug from apple?

Anybody has faced this issue before?

I'm using device without sim, that can be reason?

Comment: Reproduced on a device with SIM.

Answer (score 0):

`canOpenURL` merely indicates whether there is an app on the device capable of handling the URL scheme (the `tel:` portion in this case).

It doesn't validate the URL in any way.  Validation isn't possible since only the destination app knows what forms a valid URL (remember you can use this function with any app's URL scheme, not just well-known schemes like `tel:`).

Apple could perhaps handle the malformed URL more gracefully, but if there is a risk that the number is empty, you need to check for that condition on your side.

Comment: hope doing so should not result in unexpected behaviour like alert without any message and title. That looks weird.

Comment: I guess, but what should the alert say "invalid phone number"?  That still doesn't help the user. It just seems like the sort of thing you can handle trivially on your side and then take whatever action you want.